# Adding Firebase FCM to reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to users in my reactjs app. I have added firebase, requested user for notification permission. That's working.

But now I want to register device token. But it's giving me error:

> Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)

Where to add `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file? How to register a service worker in react app?

Here is the code I am using to register device token:

```
messaging.getToken()
      .then(function(currentToken) {
        if (currentToken) {
         // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
         // updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
        } else {
          // Show permission request.
          console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
          // Show permission UI.
        //  updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
        //  setTokenSentToServer(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        //showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
        //setTokenSentToServer(false);
      });
```

Note: It's not **react native** but a web app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file into my public directory (with index.html) file. That resolved the issue.

See more at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525074/firebase-cloud-message-notifications-are-not-receiving-js/46526005#46526005)

Comment: Noman Ali I have the same problem (I am totally new to web ), can you explain/share your code in app.js and firebase-messaging-sw.js ? Did you register your service worker?

Comment: [App.js](https://pastebin.com/CAwYtdnn) , Good luck bro. Note: You will need to setup cloud functions in order to send push notifications.

Comment: How did u register  "firebase-messaging-sw.js"? I am always get the same error when I try to register that file.

Comment: can you tell me where did you put your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file?

Comment: in /src (my app.js , index.js are also there), I think that something wrong with my path when i try to register service worker.

Comment: You have to put your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file into `YOUR_PROJECT/public/` directory. NOT in `YOUR_PROJECT/src` directory.

Comment: Thanks mate, I don't even need to register it. Only to put it in public. I tried to put it in /src and /root where all my app.js and index but apparently it always picked the wrong path even with .env. such a waste of time.