# VueJS App and Firebase messaging error

Tags: firebase, vue.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi im trying to make push notifications work for my application but i cant seem to make it run with my Vue App

I keep getting this error:

> Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)

I dont know how to handle it.

This is my Main.js:

```
let config = {
 apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 authDomain: 'vue-notify.firebaseapp.com',
 databaseURL: 'https://vue-notify.firebaseio.com',
 projectId: 'vue-notify',
 storageBucket: 'vue-notify.appspot.com',
 messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

This is the function in a component where I call the firebase.messaging()

```
subscribe () {
  firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => firebase.messaging().getToken())
    .then((token) => console.log(token))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Would be nice to know what i need to do

Comment: I explained how to configure an Vue app to handle notifications in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153913/9661304

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526034/1363486) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525074/firebase-cloud-message-notifications-are-not-receiving-js/46526005#46526005) it seems you have to put the config in a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in your public directory.